# My JS for detecting light/dark mode doesn't work right

Tags: javascript

This code is meant to detect if a user has a previously chosen color theme, and if not it should check whether they have dark mode enabled and set that corresponding theme, otherwise just set the theme to light mode. However, when I load up the page in incognito mode (so there's no `localStorage` data), no color theme loads. And when I go to a page with different code (code with the `localStorage` part but no `matchMedia`), choose a color theme, and go back to this page, that color theme doesn't show up either. I think there might be a simple syntax error because the code looks fine but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
function setTheme(themeName) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
}

(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme')) {
        setTheme(localStorage.getItem('theme'))
    } else {
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', event => {
            if (event.matches) {
                setTheme('theme-simple-dark')
            } else {
                setTheme('theme-simple-light')
            }
        })
    }
}());
```

Comment: for that you can't really depend on the `localstorage()`, you can use other data storing methods like storing theme in the DB (if you're using DB), else it's highly impossible to make this.

Comment: "when I load up the page in incognito mode (so there's no `localStorage` data), no color theme loads" — because the only thing you are doing in case there is no `localStorage` data is set up a listener. You would want to react then and there to the currently selected theme. You would also want to set up a `change` listener whether or not `localStorage` value was found.

Comment: @CodeBug I know I can't depend on `localStorage` when I'm in incognito (or when someone visits the site for the first time, which is what I was trying to emulate), so that's why there's other code. The localStorage part is only there for returning visitors who have selected their preferred color theme, and that part of the code has worked in the past. My problem is with adding in the `matchMedia` part, because I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @Amadan Wait, isn't that what the code is doing? Doesn't this part of the code: `.addEventListener('change', event => { if (event.matches)` do exactly what you're saying?

Comment: What it does do: wait till you change the theme, then call `setTheme`. What it does not do: check theme when the page loads and `setTheme` to match. What else it does not do: detect theme changing afterwards if the value was found in `localStorage`. (Disclaimer: Haven't tried it, this is just by reading code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with my comments, here's the reworked code. I also did a bit of DRYing up. Again, I have not tested it, may contain errors. `setTheme` is unchanged from yours.

```
function setThemeBool(dark) {
    if (dark) {
        setTheme('theme-simple-dark');
    } else {
        setTheme('theme-simple-light');
    }
}

(function() {
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    const themeQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
    // is anything stored from before?
    if (storedTheme) {
        // yes, use that
        setTheme(storedTheme);
    } else {
        // no, ask the browser
        setThemeBool(themeQuery.matches);
    }
    // regardless, from now on, if the theme changes, switch accordingly
    themeQuery.addEventListener('change', event => {
        setThemeBool(event.matches);
    });
}());
```

Comment: I've tested it out and it doesn't work. I've been scouring the code for mistakes but I can't find anything at all. When I load the page for the first time (in Incognito to emulate visiting the site for the first time), no color theme loads. However, if I visit the site in a normal browser window, my stored preferred theme automatically comes up, so that's good. I just can't figure out why it won't load dark theme or light theme (I've tested with both) on initial load.

Comment: Oh crap I just realized some unrelated code I had was screwing with it. It works perfectly, thank you so much!